# Open external application from chrome?

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-nativeclient, external-application

I'm developing an app which opens any external application from chrome. I would do it with NPAPI, but Chrome will drop its support. And some says the only way it can be achieved with Native Messaging or Native Client, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I tried this in Native Client but `system` call doesn't work.

In javascript:

```
naclModule.postMessage('start notepad'); // just an example, I handle it in different way.
```

In C++:

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
    if (!var_message.is_string())
      return;
    system("start notepad.exe");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Client does not allow you to open an external program; it provides the same functionality that is available in JavaScript.

Only [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) allows you to connect to an executable on the user's machine.